# React: Cannot set state from onchange event handler on form select

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that is structured like this.
I would like to capture the user's selection when they select from a drop-down.

I get the following error message when I try it:

*"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"*

I am following the example in the docs, so where am I going wrong?

```
export default class SearchPage extends Component {

....

handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        params: {
            ...this.state.params,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
    })
}

render() {
    const { county, cause, activity } = this.state

    return (
        <div className="searchpage">
            <form>
               <select name="county" onChange={this.handleChange}
               .....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handleChange` wasn't bound to the instance. You need either use inline arrow function that will capture `this` lexically

```
<select name="county" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}
```

or (recommended way) bind methods within constructor.

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: I'm using the _.bind(this)_ workaround at the moment, but it's throwing linting errors, apparently using _.bind(this)_ is quite bad for performance.  Using _onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}_ seems like the best option - thanks Yury!

Comment: Bind is ok if done once within constructor. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding

Comment: actually that is a good way to do, just tried binding in constructor, works well

Answer (score 0):

This is another trick to avoid binding your function with .bind(this) or some decorators or create anonymous function like () => myfunc()

```
handleChange => (e) { }
```

Then you can use this as you want inside